# Is there a way to do an INSERT INTO SELECT statement while specifying a commit count?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

DB: Oracle 11g

Is there a way to do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO T1
    (V1, V2)
COMMIT EVERY X
AS
SELECT (V1, V2) FROM T2;
```

I know how to loop through cursor, but I'm looking for something more streamlined.

PL/SQL is fine, but no looping.
Using a SQL Hint is good too.

If this is just something that oracle can't handle, sadness ensues (Mostly I'm just curious since I have another approach working already).

NOTE: The application has hundreds of billions of records. Millions are created per day. INSERT INTO SELECT doesn't work on such large sets of data. Especially when there are equally large sets running in parallel.

Comment: As you can see from the responses, there is generally a consensus to not have intermediate commits, which I strongly agree with. I'm curious, however, as to why you want to have an intermediate commit? What is the need?

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work"?  It's relatively common in data warehouses to be doing large numbers of `INSERT ... SELECT` statements in different sessions simultaneously during loads.

Comment: In response to the question of why I would want this: The application has hundreds of billions of records. Millions per day of data. INSERT INTO SELECT doesn't work on such large sets of data. Especially when there are equally large sets running in parallel. Also Cursors and FORALL's are bulky and ugly. But mostly, I am just curious.

Comment: Note: There are extremely large sets of data. Not a large number of small sets of data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow a statement to have interim commits, no.  Doing so would violate the basic properties of an ACID database.  What happens if the statement fails on row N?  Oracle wouldn't be able to roll back the previously committed rows.  It wouldn't know which rows had been processed and which hadn't been processed.  So your statement would be partially successful and your database would be left in an unknown state.  One of the major benefits of using a relational database is to avoid exactly that outcome.

Why do you want to do an interim commit in the first place?  That's going to make your code slower and cause you to use more resources.  It's going to force you write a bunch of code to make your process restartable (i.e. you'd have to track which rows had been processed and which hadn't so that you could either roll back partially complete changes or restart the process if it fails in the middle).  And it's going to make your code much harder to test.  There is almost never a good reason to do an interim commit.

Comment: I don't understand why this would violate acid? It only changes the atomic unit from statement to row. No reason why Oracle shouldn't be able to handle that (in principle). Of course it is probably still a bad idea.

Comment: @JensSchauder - ACID, at a minimum, has to apply to a logical statement.  If you start to allow a single SQL statement to partially complete and partially fail, the database would always be at risk of having inconsistent data-- the statement that moves money from A to B could succeed in removing the money from A but then fail to add the money to B (or vice versa) and it would be insanely difficult to write code that would correctly handle that.

Comment: Don't agree. Your example (in most settings) is actually two statements and there is no (technical) problem in putting a commit between it.

Comment: @JensSchauder - While, agreed, most of the time you'd write two statements (and thus need a transaction to wrap it), nothing prevents you from writing a single SQL statement that implements both parts of the transaction.  Nothing also prevents you from, say, writing a SQL statement that violates constraints while the SQL statement is running so long as the constraints are valid at the end.  In either case, if you allow the statement to partially succeed and partially fail, the statement is, by definition, no longer atomic.

Comment: Of course the statement isn't atomic any longer. But ACID does not talk about statements but transactions. A transaction has to be atomic. There is no real conceptual problem in the first 1000 rows of a insert statement being part of one and the second 1000 rows being part of the next transaction.

Comment: @JensSchauder - Atomicity requires that a transaction either completely fail or completely succeed.  Consistency requires that a transaction bring the database from one valid state to another valid state.  A statement that partially succeeds and partially fails would not take the database from one valid state to another and would not be atomic.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle doesn't provide such a SQL construct. Using PL/SQL with a cursor and the FORALL statement can do it for you ... BUT:

It's good that Oracle doesn't provide such sadness. Oracle is an RDBMS that is build upon the ACID principles. The I stands for isolation which, in Oracle, defaults to READ COMMITTED. Meaning that other concurrent transactions can't see your transaction half way through. It prevents other sessions from seeing inconsistent data. One of the cornerstones of using an RDBMS.

Which brings us to the most important question here: Why would you ever want such a construct?

I hope it is not fear of "big" transactions.

Comment: Hardware limitations apply to 'fear of "big" transaction'. Especially when there are multiple session going.

Comment: You just need to size your undo to fit your requirements. I still have to encounter the first system where undo could not be sized because of hardware limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check it, but perhaps with `bulk inserts` you can achieve this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF T2%ROWTYPE;
  l_data ARRAY;
  x NUMBER;

  CURSOR c IS SELECT V1, V2 FROM T2;

BEGIN
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
    FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO l_data LIMIT x;

    FORALL i IN 1..l_data.COUNT
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES l_data(i);

    COMMIT;

    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END;
```

**But as Justin Cave, WHy ???**

Comment: We've used the FORALL successfully, like I said, I was curious if you would do this without loops.